# Why interrupts are entering the datapath at decode stage in many riscv project?

Tags: cpu-architecture, riscv, risc

The explanation below is taken from [the boom's documentation](https://docs.boom-core.org/en/latest/sections/reorder-buffer.html?highlight=interrupt).

> all other exceptions and interrupts can be handled before the instruction is dispatched to the ROB

I understand the interrupts are taken at the decode stage. I assume it is placed at ROB and fires when it comes to the head of ROB (I assume in this way because CSRs are not renamed so it cannot be executed speculatively).  In this way, an interrupt might fire too late according to the size of ROB and the fullness of ROB. Isn't it a problem? What should be the correct implementation when we think of out-of-order architecture with up to hundreds of instructions in the pipe after decode stage?

Comment: I gave an example from BOOM. However, it is implemented in the same way in different cores too if I understand them correctly. ex: Ariane, ibex. They are at least in order cores that can be acceptable. However, I strongly believe that it shouldn't be taken from the decode stage in the cores that can have many instructions between the decode and retire stages.

Comment: And "Krazy" Glew's answer on [When an interrupt occurs, what happens to instructions in the pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8902132) provides a lot of insight into possible implementation strategies.  (Keep in mind that ROB capacity was only 40 entries in first-gen Intel P6 (Pentium Pro / Pentium II), the design he mentions in that answer, which he worked on at Intel.)  The standard method is to roll back to the current retirement state, discarding the ROB.  The whole point of a ROB is to allow -of-order speculative execution, so discarding has to be possible.

Comment: @PeterCordes So should I understand that interrupt is entered to rob and all the instructions are flushed(via rollback) and interrupt is retired? If it is like that, it seems there is no possibility of waiting for a huge buffer to take an interrupt.

Comment: An interrupt isn't like an instruction; it doesn't "enter the ROB" in terms of sitting in an entry in the ROB.  External interrupts give the CPU a choice of making it happen between any two instructions (unless interrupts are disabled, then it has to wait until it retires an instruction that re-enables interrupts).  This choice is made in terms of how the control logic is implemented, presumably looking at the retirement state, and probably similar to retiring a faulting load or store or other synchronous exception (trap).

Comment: But yes, as Andy Glew explained, the standard design choice is to choose for the interrupt to happen as early as possible, or maybe wait for one more instruction to retire to ensure forward progress of the non-interrupt code.  (I think that's what Intel does, unless there's some other reason for perf counter interrupts to often be late by 1 instruction.) The other possible choice is to wait for the ROB to drain, which as he says could have made sense for P6 with the ROB not being huge, and the scheduler for un-executed uops being even smaller. x86 isn't generally used for hard realtime